# ¿Cómo ocultar y mostrar div en HTML a través de un buscador de texto?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola estoy guiándome con un ejemplo de tabla que encontre pero me cuesta entender un poco jquery. Si bien lo que quiero hacer aqui es sin recargar página y sea lo más dinámico posible ya que como los datos estarán impresos en el HTML creo que sería más rapido que andar haciendo consultas AJAX y hay mostrar las palabras que sean parecidas. [Me guío con este script para hacer el buscador](https://gist.github.com/joelalejandro/8dbc55f520807673356c9cc38a4eeded)

El tema va que el ejemplo de git va en tablas y en el que tengo va en div. ¿Alguna recomendación de cómo mostrar y ocultarlo? y ¿es óptimo hacer el buscador dinámico con los datos impresos?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML

```
Cabecera donde esta el buscador. 

<div class="form-group chat-search-data m-0">
  <input type="search" class="form-control round" id="searchBox" name="name" placeholder="Buscar" data-target="search-translates">
</div>

<div class="chat-content scroller">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 search-translates">
      <div class="checkbox text-left">
        <label id="1" class="form-label"><input style="margin: 30px 0 0 0;" name="translates[]" type="checkbox" value="1"> Edificio Vive Lérida</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 search-translates">
      <div class="checkbox text-left">
        <label id="2" class="form-label"><input style="margin: 30px 0 0 0;" name="translates[]" type="checkbox" value="2"> Edificio</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4 search-translates">
      <div class="checkbox text-left">
        <label id="3" class="form-label"><input style="margin: 30px 0 0 0;" name="translates[]" type="checkbox" value="3"> Edificio Alto Maipo</label>
      </div>
    </div>                                                                                                                                                                    
  </div>
</div>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('[type="search"]').each(function(){
        var search = $(this);

        var data = $('#' + search.data('target'));

        search.on('keyup', function(){
            //Valido si viene vacio
            if (search.val().trim() === '') {
                //Muestro todas las filas
                $('input',data).show();
            } else {
                //Muestro solo las que tiene un parecido
                $('input', data).hide();
            }
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres hacer es mostrar el div segun la palabra agregada puedes obtener el valor del texbox y usar un simple if para comprobar si es igual al valor con el que quieres mostrarlo, algo asi.

```
jQuery("input").change(function(){
let texbox = jQuery('#texbox').val();

if ( texbox == 'Texto de la busqueda' ) {
jQuery('#div').attr("style","display:block;");
} else {
jQuery('#div').attr("style","display:none;");
}
});
```

Si lo que quieres es comprobar que el texbox no este vacio puedes hacer lo mismo, solo que en
`texbox == 'Texto de la busqueda'` puedes poner `texbox == ''`

El ejemplo funcionara solo si estas usando Jquery

En el html, tu input de busqueda debe tener un id, al igual que tu div a mostrar u ocultar

```
<input id="texbox" type="text" placeholder="Buscar">
<div id="div" style="display:none;">Div a mostrar</div>
```